# Bitshifts in OpenCV C++

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to rightshift all the pixels of a Image by 1 bit. I don't see any vectorized way to do this. As of now, the only solution that I have is as follows

```
void round_down(cv::Mat& image) {
int channels = image.channels();
int num_rows = image.rows;
int num_cols = (image.cols * channels);

if (image.isContinuous()) {
    num_cols *= num_rows;
    num_rows = 1;
}

for (int i = 0; i < num_rows; ++i) {
    uchar* row_ptr = image.ptr<uchar>(i);
    for (int j = 0; j < num_cols; ++j) {
        row_ptr[j] >>= 1;
    }
}
```

}

Are there any OpenCV C++ functions for bitwise leftshift and right shifts?
If not what is the best time optimized way to do it ?

Comment: `>=` is a comparison, not a shift...

Comment: Bit-shift is equivalent to a per-component multiplication or division by a power of 2. Those are supported.

Comment: simply `image *= 2;`

Comment: @DanMašek It was typo. corrected it to >>= 

OpenCV C++ is doing round away from zero for division.  If it does a truncating division then it would be equivalent to right shift.
```c++
cv::Vec4b rgba{77, 78,79,80 };
rgba /= 2;
cout << rgba;
// Outputs
[38, 39, 40, 40]  // 79/2 = 39    whereas 79>>1 is 38
```